# Is there a function that can combine more than 30 ranges together into one (other than union because I have too many ranges)?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to select 39 ranges at once normally I have been using the union method on VBA but this only accepts 30 ranges. Does anyone know a way around this?????

Comment: There is a limit if you try to union all in one shot, but you can union many more if you build up the range step-by-step

Comment: You really should show what code you have &/or what you've tried, regardless of how irrelevant you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit if you try to union all in one shot, but you can union many more if you build up the range step-by-step

```
Dim a as range, b as range, c as range, d as range, rngAll as range

'...set the ranges a-d

Set rngAll = Application.union(a, b, c, d) '<< limited to 30 ranges

'...but no limit with this incremental method  
Set rngAll = Application.union(a, b)
Set rngAll = Application.union(rngAll, c)
Set rngAll = Application.union(rngAll, d)
```